# How can I make Django url regular expression not to catch all words?

Tags: regex, django

This is my project's url patterns :

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex) /snu/
    url(r'^$', views.site_list, name='site_list'),

    # ex) /snu/cse/
    url(r'^(?i)(?P<site_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),

    # ex) /snu/cse/post/3
    url(r'^(?i)(?P<site_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),

    # ex) /snu/cse/post/3/remove
    url(r'^(?i)(?P<site_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),

    # ex) /snu/upload
    url(r'^(?i)upload/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
]
```

Unfortunately, `r'^(?i)(?P<site_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/$'` catches everything so `/snu/upload` doesn't work as I expected.

Something like `r'^(?i)(?P<site_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/upload$'` might works, but I don't want it. It should be `r'^(?i)upload/$'`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order matters in pattern matching for URL dispatcher. The first match is resolved and returned.

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

So you might want to move the "specific" patterns higher up.

In other words, move

```
# ex) /snu/upload
url(r'^(?i)upload/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
```

to the second position.

- [Documentation can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Comment: Oh, I had tried that before posting this question and didn't work.. but this time it works... kinda strange!;; Thanks :)